# How does one calculate or even approximate the force observed by a magnet as its dropped inside of a diamagnetic cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, dipole

How does one calculate or even approximate the force observed by a magnet as its dropped inside of a diamagnetic cylinder?

Wikipedia and Google does not provide much information on this topic. Wikipedia suggest to calculate the change in magnetic energy with respect to position, however I am unsure how the velocity should play a role as well.

Comment: You basically have to calculate the field as a function of position and, if the tube is conductive, as a function of velocity. In general that's a numerical problem best left to appropriate software tools. There may be a closed form solution for a strictly cylindrical geometry using either a perfect dipole or a cylindrical current as the source of the magnetic field.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have the magnetic field, for a cylinder. I want to perturb the motion to see what the reaction force is.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am under the assumption that the force grows with velocity. I am unsure how to include velocity in the problem. Does the contribution of the velocity to the force arise from the delayed reflection of the magnetic field off of the diamagnetic cylinder?

Comment: Diamagnetism is independent of velocity. It's the conductivity of the walls that creates eddy-currents that cause an additional velocity dependent force. Sometimes that's also called diamagnetism, but that's a misnomer. I don't know what you mean by "delayed reflection". That's not how magnetic fields work. You have to solve Maxwell's equations with matter for slowly changing magnetic fields, which allows you to drop the displacement current term.

Comment: @CuriousOne Does the velocity dependent force also depend on the resistance experienced by the eddy-currents?

Comment: Absolutely. The eddy-currents will decay because of the resistance, the decay time depends on the conductivity of the metal. The higher the conductivity, the slower the decay. In a superconductor there is no decay of these currents, which then looks like perfect diamagnetism, but that's different from the quantum mechanical explanation of actual diamagnetism. One way to look at it is as a skin-effect problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am unsure if the magnetic field from the magnet must take time to travel across the distance between the magnet and the cylinder. This would mean there would be a delay between the cylinder's reflection of the magnetic field back at the magnet. I think the superposition of these fields creates a large magnetic field, suggesting an additional velocity dependent force. Is this correct, or am I supposed to use something else to calculate the velocity dependent force?

Comment: The falling magnet creates a changing magnetic flux that generates current that induces an EMF in the pipe wall.  The induced EMF will act counter to the magnet's field as it enters the pipe, and will augment the magnet's field as it leaves the pipe.  This may be of help (the authors do consider velocity, and they may tell you how to compute velocity as the magnet transits the pipe):  http://www2.fisica.unlp.edu.ar/materias/FEIII/OLD/2012/AJP000193.pdf  (Apologies if this is not on point.)

Comment: If we assume that your magnet is moving slowly (compared to the speed of light), the interaction can be assumed to be instantaneous. The magnetic field causes eddy currents in each cylindrical layer of the metal tube's wall and those currents cause a force on the magnetic field. The integration over all of these leads to the total force. The velocity dependence is a consequence of $\dot\Phi$ being dependent on the velocity of the magnet (its proportional to $v_{magnet}$).

Comment: @Ernie It looks like superconductors do not produce this same effect, because they have no resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In diamagnetic material a magnetic dipole moment will develop in presence of external field. Magnetic dipole moment per volume is:

$$\mathbf{M}=\chi\mathbf{H}= {\chi\mathbf{B} \over \mu}={1 \over \mu_0}{\chi \over \chi+1}\mathbf{B}$$

In a non-uniform magnetic field there would be a force on a magnetic dipole:

$$\mathbf{F}=\nabla (\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{B})$$

One could integrate this over the cylinder to find the force:

$$\mathbf{dF}=\nabla(\mathbf{dm}\cdot\mathbf{B})=\nabla(\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{B})dv={1 \over \mu_0}{\chi \over \chi+1}\nabla(B^2)dv$$

$$\mathbf{F}={1 \over \mu_0}{\chi \over \chi+1}\int_{V_{cylinder}} \nabla(B^2)dv$$

But we still need magnetic field of the magnet. We can assume a uniform magnetic moment per volume $\mathbf{M}$ for it and find the field by integrating dipole field over the magnet volume:

$$\mathbf{B(\mathbf{r})}={\mu_0 \over 4\pi} \int_{V_{magnet}} [{3 (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})(\mathbf{M}\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}))\over (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})^5}-{\mathbf{M}\over (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})^3}] dv$$

This does not include velocity dependent force due to eddy currents mentioned in the comments.

**Update** I'll post the solution of a similar (and simplified) problem which you could later extend to your own problem.

Here we have a ring instead of cylinder with inductance L, resistance R, radius r, and mass m. And instead of magnet dropping we assume that the ring is dropping toward the magnet.

To make it simpler again we assume a linear z dependence for $B_z$ component of the magnet's magnetic field: $B_z = B_0(1-\alpha z)$

Due to symmetry $B_\phi=0$ so $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$ implies that ${\partial{B_\rho}\over{\partial \rho}}=B_0 \alpha$ then $B_\rho(\rho)=B_0 \alpha \rho + C$

Since $B_\rho(\rho=0)=0$ we have $B_\rho(\rho)=B_0 \alpha \rho$ and $B_\rho(r)=B_0 \alpha r$

Taking up as positive z direction and counter-clockwise as positive direction for current in the ring:

$$ \tag{1}
F = m \ddot z = -2\pi r I B_\rho(r) - m g = -2\pi r^2 \alpha I B_0 -mg
$$

As for current we have:

$$
\phi = \pi r^2 B_0 (1-\alpha z)\\
\epsilon_{emf} = -\dot \phi = \pi r^2 B_0 \alpha \dot z\\
\epsilon_{emf} - R I - L \dot I = 0$$ $$
\pi r^2 B_0 \alpha \dot z - R I - L \dot I = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Now we find $I$ and $\dot I$ from Eq. 1 and substitute in Eq. 2

$$
\pi r^2 B_0 \alpha \dot z - R {m(\ddot z + g) \over 2\pi r^2 \alpha B_0} - L {m\dddot z \over 2\pi r^2 \alpha B_0} = 0\\
\dddot z + {R \over L} \ddot z + {2 \pi^2 r^4 \alpha^2 B_0^2 \over m L} \dot z + {R \over L}g = 0\\
v \equiv \dot z \quad
\omega_0^2 \equiv {2 \pi^2 r^4 \alpha^2 B_0^2 \over m L} \quad
\gamma \equiv {R \over 2L} \quad {\omega_0^2 v_t} \equiv {R \over L}g\\
\ddot v + 2\gamma \dot v + \omega_0^2 v + \omega_0^2 v_t = 0
$$

Now you can see that the velocity has a damped oscillation around the terminal velocity.

Comment: Cool answer. What about the velocity? Does that contribute? What happens if the resistance is zero.

Comment: @linuxfreebird yes as mentioned by others in case the cylinder is a conductor. With zero resistanc it just oscillates (without damping) because the cylinder still has inductance. If the cylinder has both resistance and inductance it falls with oscillations in the velocity (this last case was one of the last year Iran physics olympiad questions).

Comment: I was unable to find the solution in http://ipho.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/problems-and-solutions_5.html#2014

Comment: @linuxfreebird IPhO is International Physics Olympiad. I said Iran's. Unfortunately it's in Persian only and not online. I shouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @linuxfreebird I've posted a (summarized and simplified) version of the solution in the update